# Is "sm-disable" flag required for nm-applet on openbox?

Tags: network-manager

Folks,

I remember to have read somewhere that nm-applet requires "--sm-disable" option when run under openbox. However, it seems to work okay when I do not specify this option. Is it still a good idea to have this option on?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

The `--sm-disable` flag isn't used anymore due to the applet no longer being session-managed ([source](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2011-May/msg00141.html)). It should be safe to use it without that flag.